# How do i find all the 3-digit numbers, whose digit sum is a prime number?

Tags: c++

In this lesson, I have to figure out how to do this using one of the operators:

1. if - else
2. for
3. while
4. do - while

I think my program should work but it does not. Help!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    int F=0;
    int s,d,e;

    for(int i=105; i<999; i++)
    {
        s=i/100;
        d=i/10 %10;
        e=i%10;

        for(int T=2; T<=(s+d+e)/2 ; T++)
        { 
            if( (s+e+d)%T == 0)
                F=1; 
        }

        if (F==0)
            cout<<i<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should give your variables meaningfull names instead of just random letters. Second of all, ident properly!

Comment: why did you skip 101, 102, or 104?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a moment to help us help you. What part of your program doesn't work? Does give an error? If so, what is it? If not, what output do you see and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: `i think my program should work but it does not.`  So what have you done to debug your program?  Which line or lines have you identified that are faulty?

Comment: If you step through the code in your head, it should be obvious.

Comment: I started from 105 because when you combine its digits and divide by 2, you get 3 and it is more than the first T, which is 2. And the meaningful names is the least of my problems. The debugger finds no problems.

Comment: Meaningfull names is just a lot easier for other people from whom you ask to debug your code. Are you allowed to create a function which checks if a number is prime? If yes, then I suggest that you check that function. Then feed all the stuff that you want into that function.

Comment: Even if this did work, it seems to be in violation of your requirements: it seems like you cannot use both `for` and `if`. That seems like a silly requirement, but if that really is your requirement, you should make sure your code adheres to it.

Comment: Excuse me? You're the one who included that requirement in the question...

Comment: According to the requirement, you can only use one `for`.  You have violated the requirements.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Oh! I guess that's another legitimate interpretation. I read it as "you can use as many `for`s as you like, but if you have any, you cannot have `if`/`while`/`do`...`while`". Indeed, "you can have one `for`, one `if`, one `while` and one `do`...`while`" is also a valid interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than generate all possible 3-digit numbers, then see if the sum of the digits in each is a prime, I'd work in the other direction: Generate all primes in the right range (there aren't very many of them, since `999` only adds up to `27`).

Then I'd generate all the three digit numbers possible from each--a couple of loops to generate the first two digits and simple subtraction to generate the third in each case.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{  
    for ( int i = 100; i < 1000; i++ )
    {
        int sum = i / 100 + i / 10 % 10 + i % 10;

        bool prime = sum == 2 || ( 2 < sum && sum % 2 );

        for ( int j = 3; prime && j * j <= sum ; j += 2 )
        {
            prime = sum % j != 0; 
        }

        if ( prime ) std::cout << "The sum " << sum 
                               << " of digits of number " << i 
                               << " is a prime number"
                               << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the statements (for example iterative statements) have to be different you can write for example

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 99;  
    while ( ++i < 1000 )
    {
        int sum = i / 100 + i / 10 % 10 + i % 10;

        bool prime = sum == 2 || ( 2 < sum && sum % 2 );

        for ( int j = 3; prime && j * j <= sum ; j += 2 )
        {
            prime = sum % j != 0; 
        }

        if ( prime ) std::cout << "The sum " << sum 
                               << " of digits of number " << i 
                               << " is a prime number"
                               << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program has one for loop, one while loop and one if statement.:)

Comment: This violates the prime directive:  "Using only one of these operators...for..".  In other words, only one `for` is allowed.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I am not sure what this directive means. I showed a correct code compared with the original code. it can be used as a template for any other modifications.

Comment: @user3714873 If you have to use only one for loop then there is no any problem to change any for loop in my code to a while loop or do-while loop. Try to do it yourself.